# Один перевод для нескольких стран

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Здравствуйте! У моего android приложения есть основной язык - это английский. Мне нужно было, чтобы пользователи, у которых стоит на телефоне русский или , например, украинский языки видели одну и ту же русскую версию приложения.  Подскажите, есть ли способ показывать один и тот же перевод (по сути один и тот же strings.xml) для нескольких стран при условии, что основным языком должен оставаться английский?

Comment: Такое поведение будет по-умолчанию.

Comment: @post_zeew Да, согласен. Но мне в данном случае нужно,чтобы по-умолчанию стоял английский язык.

Comment: В чём проблема предоставить выбор языка?

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность программно заменить текущий язык приложения. Но это нужно делать в `onCreate()` всех Activity перед `setContentView()`. Если язык не зависит от выбора пользователя в приложении, это overkill.

Для меня самым простым было бы написать скрипт, который парсил cуществующие xml со строками и создавал недостающие по определенным правилам (копировал русские строки в украинский язык при их отсутствии).

Создать в проекте модуль типа Java Library, в нем создать класс с `public static void main(...)`, путь к файлам задать относительно рабочего каталога (он будет внутри каталога проекта и не будет меняться). С Java и парсерами вы, очевидно, работать уже умеете.

Дальше надо сформулировать правила замены языков, что-то вроде "Берем все строки из `values/strings.xml`, дополняем и заменяем строками из `values-ru/strings.xml`, убираем оттуда строки, присутствующие в `values-ua/strings.xml`, результат записываем в `values-ua/generated.xml`". И реализовать.

Запускать скрипт периодически по желанию и перед релизом.